# Compile Error: Variable does not exist: UserOrGroupId, any help to solve this caseshare issue?

Tags: apex, apex-managed-sharing

```
public class Caseshare {


    public static void CaseInsert(list<case> caseNewList) {

        map<id, recordtype> caseRecTyp = new map<id, recordtype>();
        caseRecTyp = new map<id, recordtype>( [select id, developername, SobjectType, Name from recordtype where name = 'Customer Community Request' or name = 'Gatekeeper Support Request' or name = 'Customer Support Request']);

        if (!caseNewList.isempty() && caseNewList != null) {
            set<id> accountIds = new set<id>();
            set<id> contactIds = new set<id>();

        map<id, list<case>> caseMap = new map<id, list<Case>>();

        for (case c: caseNewList) {
                    if (caseRecTyp.containskey(c.recordtypeid)) {
                        accountIds.add(c.accountid);

                        if (!caseMap.containskey(c.accountid) && caseMap.get(c.accountid) == null) {
                        caseMap.put(c.accountid, new list<case>());
                            caseMap.get(c.accountid).add(c);
                        } else {
                            caseMap.get(c.accountid).add(c);
                        }

                    }

                }

            for (contact c : [select id, accountid, status__c from contact where accountid in: accountIds and status__c = 'Active']) {
                contactIds.add(c.id);
            }

            map<id, list<user>> communityUser = new map<id, list<user>>();

            for (user utemp : [select id, name, usertype, contactid, accountid, profile.usertype from user where contactid in:contactIds and profile.usertype = 'PowerCustomerSuccess']) {
                if (communityUser.get(utemp.accountid) == null && communityUser.containskey(utemp.accountid)) {
                    communityUser.put(utemp.accountid, new list<user>());
                    communityUser.get(utemp.accountid).add(utemp);

                } else {
                    communityUser.get(utemp.accountid).add(utemp);
                }
            }

            List<CaseShare> csList = new list<CaseShare>();
            if (communityUser != null && communityUser.size() > 0) {

                for (id i : communityUser.keyset()) {

                    for (user u : communityUser.get(i)) {

                    for (case c: caseMap.get(i)) {
                                caseShare cso = new caseShare();
                                cso.UserOrGroupId = u.id;
                                //cso.CaseId = c.id;
                                //cso.CaseAccessLevel ='Read';
                                //csList.add(cso);
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (csList.size() > 0 && csList != null) {
                //   insert csList;
            }
        }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code You tried to access class field `UserOrGroupId` but this class field was not defined in `CaseShare` class definition. **rename your class from CaseShare to something else because this is confused with sObject name**

You can validate it by running the code below from developer console.

```
public class CaseShare {
    public String name;

    public CaseShare() {
        this.name = 'test';
    }

    public static void test() {            
        CaseShare caseShare = new CaseShare();
        System.debug(caseShare);
    }
}
```

Comment: Really sorry for responding this late, yet it was problem with the class name, I have changed it from caseshare to Ucaseshare which solved the issue.